# Gatsby custom source one to many

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I'm following the source plugin tutorial, and all goes well until I try to link my nodes.

My data structure is the following:

```
  type Genre implements Node {
    id: ID!
    itemsCount: Int
    imageUrl: String!
    name: String!
    items: [Movie]
  }
type Movie implements Node {
    id: ID!
    advisory: [String]!
    cast: [String]!
    title: String!
}
```

in my data fetching I can then simply do

```
const genres = fetch(api/genres); // genres have genres.items which is an array of movies

genres.forEach(genre =>  createNode({   ...genre, id: createNodeId(genre.id) }));
genres.items.forEach((movie => createNode({   ...movie, id: createNodeId(movie.id) }));
```

All of the data is added correctly and I can query allGenres and allMovies ... but when I try to query genre items it returns null;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out what I can do is:

```
  type Genre implements Node {
    id: ID!
    itemsCount: Int
    imageUrl: String!
    name: String!
    items: [Movie]! @link
  }
type Movie implements Node {
    id: ID!
    advisory: [String]!
    cast: [String]!
    title: String!
    genre: Genre @link(by: "title")
}
```

and then something like:

```
genres.forEach(genre =>  { 
   // save movie ids from map
   const movies = genres.items.map((movie => {
     // create movie node - assign genre title as a field on movie
     createNode({   ...movie, genre: genre.title })

     return movie.id;
   });

   // create genre node - assign items as an array of ids from movies
   createNode({   ...genre, items: movies  });
});

There was no need to use gatsby id as my id's were unique already. Here my linking is done from Genre to Movie using @link ( it defaults to using id as the key ) and then from Movie to Genre using @link(by: "title") where I have specified to use the title attribute as the key
```

Comment: so it turns my solution was good before '@link' era ;)   ... wouldn't be more natural to link `genre` by `id`, not by `title`? this looks like more redundant

Answer (score 1):

`items` contains array of ids only, not array of `Movies`

[Naively - inspired by Apollo local] I would expect to

1. collect movies into an `id` indexed object.
2. for each `genre`

   - convert `items` into array of `Movies` (create `movie` nodes [if not exists])
   - create `genre` node

... but probably it's enough [I'm naive?] to create `Movie` nodes first and annotate `item: [Movie] @link(from: "Movie___NODE")`.

You have to dig into API or internals of some source plugins or just search on gatsby issues for examples.

At the end it probably should look like:

```
...genres.map(genre => {
  const content = {
    itemsCount: genre.itemsCount,
    imageUrl: genre.imageUrl,
    name: genre.name,
    ["items___NODE"]: genre.items.map(id =>
    createNodeId(`Movie{${id}}`),
    ),
  };
  const id = createNodeId(`Genre{${genre.id}}`);
  const nodeContent = JSON.stringify(content);
  createNode({
    ...content,
    id,
    parent: null,
    children: [],
    internal: {
      type: `Genre`,
      content: nodeContent,
      contentDigest: crypto
        .createHash("md5")
        .update(nodeContent)
        .digest("hex"),
    },
  });
});
```

It's inspired by [this use case](https://spectrum.chat/gatsby-js/general/how-to-link-related-nodes~58d63a0a-ef5f-4dc7-8238-d3220d1133db?m=MTU0NDY1MDc2OTM1MQ==) (self type referencing).

Comment: So I actually tried this ( but backwards - referencing a genre from a movie such I could do `Movie.genre.title`

When I mapped my movies, I added a `genre: genre.id` field, and then in the type added: `genre: Genre @Link` and even that returns null :/

Comment: `genre: createNodeId(`Genre{${genre.id}}`)` ? You need to use gatsby node ids, not original ones [for relations]